# How to Get ListView Section Header to Stick

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

I have buttons displayed on the top of the screen (used **react-native-scrollable-tab-view**). Underneath the buttons, I have `ListView` with section header on it.

> Is there a way to get the header to stick to the bottom edge of the tab-view when I am scrolling?

[image]

I have had a hard time trying to get `ListView`'s section header to stick to the bottom of Facebook TabBar, and its default is to stick to the top of the screen.

When I scroll, the section header slides under the tab-bar.

> Any thoughts on this? Is there anything I should change in FacebookTabBar.js to make this work?

***Without tab bar at the top***

[image: nobar]

***With tab bar at the top***

***Note***: It is strange how this GIF does not show the full animation correctly; you can imagine that the list is scrolled a lot and the section header slides under the tab bar.

[image: withbar]

***Section header styles***

```css
catListHeaderContainer: {
    padding: 12,
    backgroundColor: '#1F2036',
}
```

***FacebookTabBar styles***

```css
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tab: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 10,
  },

  tabs: {
    height: 60,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingTop: 5,
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderLeftWidth: 0,
    borderRightWidth: 0,
    borderBottomColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
  },

  activeTabTitle: {
    marginTop: 40,
    color: '#3B5998',
  },

  nonActiveTabTitle: {
    marginTop: 40,
    color: '#BDBDBD',
  },

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now if you take a look at [this code](https://gist.github.com/jpjhpq/8117845dd59da9095265), you may notice that `Category` is a direct child of `ScrollView` (the tag with `tabTitle='Search'`).

My attempt to make this work was to let `View` be the direct child of `ScrollView` and write `Category` as the child of `View`.

```html
<ScrollView tabTitle='Search' tabLabel="ion|ios-search" style={styles.tabView}>
  <View style={styles.categoryContain}>
    <Category/>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Then I styled `View` in the following way:

```css
categoryContain: {
  top: 0,
  height: deviceHeight,
},
```

This seems to have solved the problem partially. Partially, because for example, if I click **Cell 2** and then pull the list up, the list view scrolls properly, and the section headers stick in the way that I expect.

However, if I initially click (continuously holding down the mouse button) and pull down the list and then try pulling it up after that, the list and its section header slide behind the tab bar thus showing the original behavior, which is not what I want to see.

***Pulling up the list***

[image]

***Initially pulling down, and then pulling up the list***

[image]

Comment: In addition to the changes that I made as shown in this post, adding scrollEnabled={false} in ScrollView fixed the problem.

Answer (score 21):

ListView Headers don't stick, you'll need to use `renderSectionHeader` and `cloneWithRowsAndSections` instead of `cloneWithRows` to do this.

From the React Native [documentation on ListView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#content)

```
renderSectionHeader function 

(sectionData, sectionID) => renderable

If provided, a sticky header is rendered for this section. The sticky behavior means that it will scroll with the content at the top of the section until it reaches the top of the screen, at which point it will stick to the top until it is pushed off the screen by the next section header.
```

I tackled this same issue today. Here's how I handled it. First, in `getInitialState`:

```
getInitialState: function() {

  return {
    dataBlob: {},
    dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
    sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2
    }),
  }
},
```

Then, during my API call that gets data back, I add that response data to my `dataBlob` object. The key that stores it is considered the `sectionId` for `ListView.DataSource`. In this case, that `sectionId` is going to be the date of the posts I retrieve:

```
  getAllPosts: function() {

    api.getAllPosts()
      .then((responseData) => {
        var tempDataBlob = this.state.dataBlob;
        var date = new Date(responseData.posts[0].day).toDateString();
        tempDataBlob[date] = responseData.posts;
        this.setState({
          dataBlob: tempDataBlob
        });
        ;
      }).then(() => {
        this.setState({
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(this.state.dataBlob),
          loaded: true
        })
      })
      .done();
  },
```

`cloneWithRowsAndSections` accepts a `dataBlob` (in my case, an object) as its first argument, and optional arguments of `sectionIDs` and `rowIDs`.

Here's how `renderListView` looks:

```
  renderListView: function() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderPostCell}
        renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
        renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
        onEndReached={() => {this.getAllPosts(this.state.currentDay)}}
        onEndReachedThreshold={40}
        style={styles.postsListView} />
      )
  },
```

And here's how `renderSectionHeader` looks:

```
  renderSectionHeader: function(sectionData, sectionID) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text style={styles.sectionText}>{sectionID}</Text>
      </View>
      )
  },
```

Here's how it looks in the end:
[image: imgur]

Comment: Thank you Richard, I'm now using cloneWithRowsAndSections. The section header is properly sticking to the top of the screen. I've been now looking into how I can get the section header to stick to a certain distance away from the top. I edited my original post to clarify what I mean. It looks like I may have to find the part of the code which tells the section header to stick to the top, maybe that will give me more information on how to proceed with getting the header to stick to a different location away from the top.

Comment: Could you show me the styling you have for your navigation/tab bar and your section header?

Comment: Thanks for the response Richard, I've updated the original post with the styles. Also I posted the ListView, FacebookTabBar, and Index code here:

https://gist.github.com/jhprks/21b728469de9ecadf4b3

https://gist.github.com/jhprks/661907acde4943eae3a6

https://gist.github.com/jhprks/8117845dd59da9095265

Comment: I think I'm a little bit closer to making this work. Please see below for my findings.

Comment: Thanks Richard, it turned out the solution was right under my nose. I updated this post with my own answer as seen below.

Comment: Fantastic, great to hear!

Comment: I think sticky headers aren't supported on Android yet.